# Eloquent model returns 0 as primary key

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this migration:

```
Schema::create('provincias', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('codigo', 2);
    $table->string('nombre', 50);
    $table->timestamp('creado');
    $table->primary('codigo');
});
```

This is my model:

```
class Provincia extends Model
{   
    protected $primaryKey = 'codigo';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

I run the migration and save data like this:

```
$provincia = new Provincia;
$provincia->codigo = "BA";
$provincia->nombre = "Buenos Aires";
$provincia->save();
```

The problem is that when I get all and dump:

```
$provincias = Provincia::all();
return $provincias;
```

The primary key "codigo" is always 0 even when I check the database table and it has the proper value:

```
{
    codigo: 0,
    nombre: "Buenos Aires",
    creado: "2015-12-24 21:00:24"
}
```

Comment: Try setting incrementing to false on the model `public $incrementing = false;` see if that works

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can try setting `public $incrementing = false;` on your model so eloquent doesn't expect your primary key to be an autoincrement primary key.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It's amazing how in Laravel 5.1 I didn't need this property but in 5.4 is asking for it.

Comment: I've just moved to Laravel 5.4 from 5.1. Thank you very much for this invaluable tip.

Comment: when i set `$incrementing = false` it doesn't return any id. i want to get primary id

Answer (score 9):

You can also set the type of primary key:

```
protected $keyType = 'string';
public $incrementing = false;
```

Important note. You should add the second line. `$incrementing = false`. If you do not this, the key will be 0 after calling `save()` on your model.

Comment: This one definitely helped me a lot. I think it's still better to be safe by adding the `keyType` as well instead of just the incrementing.