# laravel eloquent string field for Primary Key goes data error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

I guess it is too much simple but goes query result error .

I made Country table , models. 
I just want it query only .

The only point not usual is that I did not use 'id' field for primary field.

I used 'cc' field for primary .

That's it. but it goes response data error .

in migration file

```
Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->string('cc')->index()->unique();
  $table->string('name_eng');
  $table->primary('cc');
});
```

in Controller

```
function run() {
  $countries = Country::OrderBy('cc', 'asc')->take(3)->get();
  $data['countries'] = $countries;
  return response()->json( $data, 200);
}
```

in Country Model

```
class Country extends Model
{
    protected $table='countries';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cc';
    public $timestamps = false;
  protected $fillable = ['cc', 'name_eng'];
}
```

in result

```
{
  "countries": [
    {
      "cc": 0, --> it should be 'ad' 
      "name_eng": "Andorra",
    },
    {
      "cc": 0, --> it should be 'ae' 
      "name_eng": "United Arab Emirates",
    },
    {
      "cc": 0, --> it should be 'af' 
      "name_eng": "Afghanistan",
    }
  ]
}
```

in backup sql

```
INSERT INTO `countries` (`cc`, `name_eng`)
VALUES
    ('ad', 'Andorra'),
    ('ae', 'United Arab Emirates'),
    ('af', 'Afghanistan');
```

Why Do I get lost 'cc' field values ?

I dont understand where the wrong comes from.

somebody can help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eloquent model returns 0 as primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458985/eloquent-model-returns-0-as-primary-key)

Answer (score 0):

In your model write `public $incrementing = false`

So model will understand that your primary key is string

Comment: Thanks. for reply.  I got another solution on Laravel 6.  in Model , I added.   protected $keyType = 'string';