# CAN'T UPDATE DATA IN LARAVEL CONTROLLER

Tags: laravel

i can't update data to database, im using postman and result is success but data not updated in my database.

this is my function in controller :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
            $dbelicpkb = DBeliCPKB::find($id);
            if(is_null($dbelicpkb)) {
                return response()->json('Spesifikasi Not Found', 404);
            }
            if($request->tanggal != $dbelicpkb["Tanggal"]){
                $dbelicpkb["Tanggal"] = $request->tanggal;
            }
            if($request->noSuplier != $dbelicpkb["No Suplier CPKB"]){
                $dbelicpkb["No Suplier CPKB"] = $request->noSuplier;
            }
            if($request->kodeBarang != $dbelicpkb["Kode Barang CPKB"]){
                $dbelicpkb["Kode Barang CPKB"] = $request->kodeBarang;
            }
            if($request->jumlah != $dbelicpkb["Jumlah"]){
                $dbelicpkb["Jumlah"] = $request->jumlah;
            }
            if($request->noLP != $dbelicpkb["No LP"]){
                $dbelicpkb["No LP"] = $request->noLP;
            }
            if($request->noBet != $dbelicpkb["No Bet"]){
                $dbelicpkb["No Bet"] = $request->noBet;
            }
            if($request->noFaktur != $dbelicpkb["No Faktur"]){
                $dbelicpkb["No Faktur"] = $request->noFaktur;
            }
            if($request->status != $dbelicpkb["Status"]){
                $dbelicpkb["Status"] = $request->status;
            }
            $success = $dbelicpkb->save();
```

And this is result when i try using POSTMAN

```
[
    "updated",
    {
        "Tanggal": "2020-01-31 00:00:00",
        "No Bukti CPKB": "2001001",
        "No Suplier CPKB": "300001",
        "Kode Barang CPKB": "1010",
        "Jumlah": "20",
        "No LP": "P2001001",
        "No Bet": "101010",
        "No Uji": "UP2001001",
        "No Faktur": "1010",
        "Status": "Belum Diuji"
    },
    true,
    200
]
```

Result is success but nothing happen in my database

This is my route

```
Route::post('dbelicpkbs/update/{id}', 'DBeliCPKBController@update');
```

and this is my model

```
class DBeliCPKB extends Model
{
     /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'dbelicpkb';
    protected $primaryKey = 'no uji';
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function HBeliPembelians()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(HBeliPembelian::class,'No Bukti');
    }

}
```

Comment: how can your primary key has a space in it ?

Comment: I would highly suggest to rename your column names. Column names with spaces would only give you more problems in the future.

Comment: SOLVED !! i got the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458985/eloquent-model-returns-0-as-primary-key

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's very bad practice to have spaces in your column names.

You have to use arrows to set attributes of given model instance:

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    $dbelicpkb = DBeliCPKB::find($id);
    if(is_null($dbelicpkb)) {
        return response()->json('Spesifikasi Not Found', 404);
    }
    if($request->tanggal != $dbelicpkb->{'Tanggal'}){
        $dbelicpkb->{'Tanggal'} = $request->tanggal;
    }
    if($request->noSuplier != $dbelicpkb->{'No Suplier CPKB'}){
        $dbelicpkb->{'No Suplier CPKB'} = $request->noSuplier;
    }
    if($request->kodeBarang != $dbelicpkb->{'Kode Barang CPKB'}){
        $dbelicpkb->{'Kode Barang CPKB'} = $request->kodeBarang;
    }
    if($request->jumlah != $dbelicpkb->{'Jumlah'}){
        $dbelicpkb->{'Jumlah'} = $request->jumlah;
    }
    if($request->noLP != $dbelicpkb->{'No LP'}){
        $dbelicpkb->{'No LP'} = $request->noLP;
    }
    if($request->noBet != $dbelicpkb->{'No Bet'}){
        $dbelicpkb->{'No Bet'} = $request->noBet;
    }
    if($request->noFaktur != $dbelicpkb->{'No Faktur'}){
        $dbelicpkb->{'No Faktur'} = $request->noFaktur;
    }
    if($request->status != $dbelicpkb->{'Status'}){
        $dbelicpkb->{'Status'} = $request->status;
    }
    $success = $dbelicpkb->save(); 
}
```

Also make sure that you have assigned that columns in your model's `$fillable` property:

```php
public $fillable = [
    'No LP',
    'No Bet'
    ...
];
```

Or make everything fillable by placing `protected $guarded = [];` in your model

Hope this answer helps you.

Comment: fillable should not be a problem since its not mass assignment

Comment: first, thankyou for your answer, but it still doesn't work for me ..

Comment: Can you try it with where condition ? 
DBeliCPKB::where('id', $id)->update([ 'some_key', 'some value']);

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:

It seems there is some issue with the method and encoding.

> PUT with x-www-form-urlencoded

It should help.